# how to guarantee initilization of a stack variable with a compile time constant

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, consteval, constinit

In C++20 we now have `constinit`. `constexpr` and `consteval`.

I can now guarantee that a static variable is initialized by the result of a `constexpr` or `consteval` function by using `constinit`. OK

I also can guarantee that a stack variable is initialized with the result of a `consteval` function executed in compile time.

But how can I force to run a `constexpr` function to calculate a result in compile time to init a variable on stack?

```
// Lets assume that we have a much more complex function so that the compiler will not
// always decide to compile time evaluation automatically 
constexpr int func( int i )
{
    return i+2;
}

int main()
{
     ??? int i = func(8);
     ...
     i = 9;
}
```

If we use `constexpr` the variable is implicitly const and `constinit` is not allowed here. Any chance to initialize this var with the compile time evaluated result of a `constexpr` function without making it const? I am simply wondering why `constinit` is limited to static variables. For my it makes not much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is better to use `consteval` function, but if you cannot change it, you can simply use a temporary variable which will surely optimize later:

```
constexpr int func( int i )
{
    return i+2;
}

int main()
{
     constexpr int i1 = func(8);
     auto i2 = i1;
     i2 = 9;
}
```

Although you may not like this method, I think it works without any problem....

You can also use something like this(Based on StoryTeller [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70650823/5529197)):

```
template<typename T> constexpr std::remove_const_t<T> const_eval(T&& res) { return res; }
```

which support returning references from method too.

Comment: what guarantuees that `i1` or `i2`  is initialized at compile time?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: `constexpr`?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `i1` is guaranteed compile time because of `constexpr`, then `i2` gets a mutable copy of `i1`.

Comment: OK, only a workaround possible... feels like a language bug to me!

Answer (score 4):

> I am simply wondering why constinit is limited to static variables. For my<sup>[sic]</sup> it makes not much sense.

Constant initialization and dynamic initialization are concepts that apply only to objects with static storage duration. The `constinit` specifier merely means to enforce our expectation that a variable will undergo the former, rather than the latter. It's not an optimization tool, but a way to codify how our code is meant to behave. Without it, dynamic initialization can happen silently, and as any C++ programmer who has been around the block can tell you, that also means the static initialization order fiasco can occur.

With `constinit`, we either get the expected behavior or a diagnostic. It doesn't apply to automatic variables because they don't suffer from the same problem static variables do.

But if you want to ensure `i` is initialized by something that *can* be constant evaluated, then it's not too hard to accomplish.

```
template<auto result> consteval auto const_eval() { return result; }

int main()
{
     int i = const_eval<func(8)>();
     i = 9;
}
```

If `func(8)` cannot be constant evaluated, it's a hard error. Will a compiler optimize it to a load of a constant value? Very likely. Compilers are good at that sort of thing.

Comment: OK, only a workaround possible... feels like a language bug to me!

Comment: @Klaus: The language provides few ways of specifying optimizations in general: the idea is that you should trust the implementation to pick what constant-folding to do just like you trust it to inline when appropriate.

Comment: @DavisHerring: My current use case and the reason why I ask is a small embedded system (AVR) with very low memory ( ram/flash ). "Trust" is not enough, it needs to have a lot of "force" to get working code! If on a PC some lines are not optimized, it is not a problem, but if interrupt handlers on a uC will not really optimized, it is a show stopper! However, it feels like a design bug that `constinit` can not be used for stack vars.

Comment: @Klaus - You keep insisted on a "design bug" while neglecting it's doing exactly what it was designed *for*. Can it be **expanded** to stack variables? Maybe. But that's something that was not part of the goal. If you are on a specific platform, you'd be better off using platform specific methods to get you that constant in a way you'll be *sure*.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: ""design bug" while neglecting it's doing exactly what it was designed for" Thats why I call it a design bug and not an implementation bug. "If you are on a specific platform, you'd be better off using platform specific methods " I want to reuse non platform specific code. If I follow at the end to guarantee all my self, I can write a code generator which puts all I need somewhere in flash and the rest is assembler... hey, we all want to use C++ because it is a good common language from uC to mainframe. If `constinit` can be used, it is a bit more perfect...